# Parent/Child classes in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, single-table-inheritance

I'm newish to Rails and working on a project that I would like to create a parent/child relationship using devise.  I've looked through a good bit of the literature on Devise, but didn't see any clear cut way to do what I'm trying to accomplish (though it's certainly possible I overlooked the answer because I was using different terminology).

**Here's what I'd like to do:**

Companies sign up using the normal devise registration flow with a little extra information - i.e. Company name, address, etc.  They then add 'users' once inside the application.  Users shouldn't have an external sign-up flow.  I would like to each user to inherit the company information from `Company`.

**Here is what I thought I'd try:**

1. Generate both the `Company` and the `User` devise models.
2. Generate the `User` controller, modify the `new` action to `@current_company.user.build`

Would this accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Any further reading that you might be able to pass along would be appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you try your own possible solutions and post here if it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this....

```
#app/models/company.rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   devise ....
   belongs_to :company
end
```

This is a [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) association.

---

What you should be doing is leaving `companies` to be its own model; don't include Devise on it at all.

Instead, you should make your `User` model the only one with the authentication. After that, each `user` will have to be related to a particular `company` (or if you wanted to use `has_many :through`, you could have a user a member of many companies).

You'd have to scope the `Devise` authentication around a company (IE `company.users.exists? user`); I've been working on that but don't have a thorough implementation yet.

There's a good ref here: [Scope login to subdomain](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Scope-login-to-subdomain)

This will allow you to have `users` for a particular `company`; which you'll be either be able to scope using `subdomains` (to make a crude ["multi tenant"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy) app), or to have a `select` box at sign-in or something.

---

Obviously, your lack of input means I've got to write a broad answer.

If I were you, I'd think about your desired [flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(software)).

Research [multi tenancy](https://gorails.com/episodes/multitenancy-with-apartment) with Rails (the [`apartment gem`](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) is good if you're using PGSQL) - this should give you a better idea on the way the application should work (IE how does a company need to support users).